# Copying and pasting multiple lines in Powershell Console with double loop

Tags: powershell

I have succeeded to copy and paste and execute multi-lines of code in Powershell Console when there is one single foreach and it doesn't work when there is 2 double nested foreach.

Anyone has succeeded ?

Comment: Can you give a simple example of what you are attempting to do?

Comment: I have pasted more complicated multiline code into the console without issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is possible.  Copy/paste the following in your PowerShell console host:

```
$mytwodimarray = @(@(1, 2), @(10, 20), @(100, 200))
foreach ($outer in $mytwodimarray) {
    foreach ($inner in $outer) {
    "inner value $inner"
    }
}
```

This succeeds, with the desired output:

```
inner value 1
inner value 2
inner value 10
inner value 20
inner value 100
inner value 200
```

In short, a nested loop won't cause your problem.  You most likely have a syntax error in your actual code.  Try running the snippet in PowerShell ISE or similar, and see if something jumps out at you.

Comment: I'm in corporate environnement I cannot have ISE only pure console. I'll try tomorrow at work.

Comment: @user310291 PowerShell ISE ships with Windows.

Comment: This does not work in Visual Studio 2019 Package Manager Console:

PM> foreach ($outer in $mytwodimarray) {
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
PM>     foreach ($inner in $outer) {
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
PM>     "inner value $inner"
inner value 
PM>     }
At line:1 char:5
+     }
+     ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
PM> }
```